# Non-class type Errors

Tags: c++

It appears that the main problem is in the variable type. Can anyone suggest some of the essential functions I should be using to correct the errors?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char input[99];
    char get[99];
    int numOfchars = 0;

    cout<<"Please input any characters or strings: ";
    cin.get(input,99);
    cout<<"Please input characters you wish to catch: ";
    cin.get(get,99);
    for (unsigned int i=0; i<input.length(); i++)
    {
        cin.get(get,99);
        if(input.at(i)==get)
        {
            numOfchars++;
        }
    }
    cout<<"Number of characters: "<<numOfchars<<endl;
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What are the errors?

Comment: To ask a good question, you should state what are you trying to do, how are you trying to do that, the code and the problem with the code

Comment: it should output numbers of characters you wished to catch for example i input sasquatch, then i wish to pick the letter or character s to catch or count

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The operator `.` is generally used to access the member functions of the class. The `char` is a pure built-in **datatype** and not a class unlike `std::string`. You can't create an object of it, but a variable. And it's commonly known that a variable is a variable, not an instance of an object that it could refer to some member functions.

You're declaring `char[]`, but not `std::string` (which is a built-in class featured by C++ standard committee), if you write the code something like (notice the explanations written in comments of code):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(void) {
    // string to be entered
    std::string string;

    // letter, not a string, to find
    char letter;

    // since the number is always positive
    unsigned int counter = 0;

    std::cout << "Enter the string: ";
    std::getline(std::cin, string); // accepting whitespaces system

    std::cout << "Enter the letter to catch: ";
    std::cin >> letter;

    for (size_t i = 0, len = string.length(); i < len; i++)
        if (string[i] == letter) // the subscript operator [] changes
            counter++;           // std::string into char, e.g. string[3] is a char

    std::cout << "The total existing letters: " << counter << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Then you'll get correct results.

Comment: ohh my thank you very much for the lift sir/mam, ill note all of the details  may god bless you

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the program should find the amount of a specific character (one single character) in an array, one alternative is to use a string instead:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string input;
    char get;
    int numOfChars = 0;

    cout<<"Please input any characters or strings: ";
    cin >> input;
    cout<<"Please input characters you wish to catch: ";
    cin >> get;
    for (int i=0; i<input.length(); i++)
    {
        if(input[i]==get)
        {
            numOfChars++;
        }
    }
    cout<<"Number of characters: "<<numOfChars;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the lift sir/mam, but i get some error in the if statement in your recent modified code.

Comment: I think this might be because my compiler uses c++17, which might be different from other versions of c++.

Comment: ohh i guess youre right. ill try to use another ide instead